# TweetNaCl TypeError: unexpected type, use Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, nacl-cryptography

I have  a problem when trying to use sign function from TweetNaCl. It always throws error unexpected type, use Uint8Array.

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl')
nacl.util = require('tweetnacl-util')

const b = nacl.sign.keyPair()
// console.log(b.secretKey) the result is already in Uint8Array form

const c = b.secretKey

const sign= nacl.sign("message", c)
//error unexpected type, use Uint8Array
```

```
nacl.sign.keyPair()
```

wil return an object containing secretkey and publickey ..
but when trying to sign

```
nacl.sign("message", privatekey)
```

error is trown

Anyone knows how to overcome this?
thank you :)

Comment: All API functions expect `Uint8Arrays`, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl#usage). `c` is of type `Uint8Array`, but `"message"` is _not_. Encoding / Decoding of strings is made possible with tweetnacl-util, [here](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-util-js#documentation).

Comment: Ah yes! thanks.. nacl.util.decodeUTF8("message")